# Query recursive Views

Tags: sql, recursive-query

Given the relation `person(name, gender, father, mother)`, with `name` as the `primary key`, and `gender` taking on values `M` and `F`, how do I write recursive views in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) to ﬁnd a list that mentions all the sisters?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What about the hundreds of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+sql)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the definition of a sister means that both parents are the same, can it be as simple as this?

```
select t2.name
from table t1 join table t2 on t1.mother = t2mother
and t1.father = t2.father

where t1.name <> t2.name
and t2.gender = 'F'
```